# aurelia search filtering using a computed is causing issues when rendering to view

Tags: javascript, typescript, search, aurelia, computed-properties

I have a search function that retrieves objects

```
this.searchForObjectByName = () => {
            this.server.get('objects/?searchTerm=' + self.searchTerm)
                .then(groupObjects=> 
                {
                    this.searchResults = groupObjects;
                });
        }
```

I then set the result of this to a property called searchResults, which are a groups of objects.
I now want to perform some filtering base on the results. Say I have some groups of objects that look like:

```
{
    id: 1, 
    name: 'group 1',
    objects: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'object name 1',
          categories: ['Cat A', 'Cat B']
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'object name 2',
          categories: ['Cat A', 'Cat D']
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'object name 3',
          categories: ['Cat C', 'Cat D']
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2, 
    name: 'group 2',
    objects: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'object name 4',
          categories: ['Cat A', 'Cat F']
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'object name 5',
          categories: ['Cat C', 'Cat D']
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to then filter to only show Cat A objects.
I have a computed that filters the search results based on selected categories:

```
get filteredSearchResults(): any[] {
    var filteredGroups = this.searchResults.map(res => {
        let filteredGroup = new Group;
        filteredGroup = res.id,
        filteredGroup = res.name;
        filteredGroup = res.objects.filter(o => this.filteredCategories.some(fc => o.categories.some(oc => oc == fc)));
        return filteredGroup;
    });

    filteredGroups = filteredGroups.filter(fg => fg.objects.length > 0);
    return filteredGroups;
}
```

This filters the results fine and I can select different categories and it filters correctly. However it jumps all over the place in the UI, the results are constantly updating due to using a computed to filter the results. I can't use the computedfrom attribute because its based on the filtered categories I've selected (that are an array) and the results returning from the server (also an array). Has anyone else experienced this issue before? Everything I try causes jitter and I'm not sure how I can do this differently.

I could trigger events when selected categories change or when data is returned from the server, I could then recalculate the filtered results. This would work but is hacky and would prefer to be able to do this in a computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without computedFrom, your property getter is being polled, which is why your interface is jumping around.  I'm not familiar with .some, but I'm guessing order is not guaranteed.  While you could simply order your search results to work around this, it would be pretty inefficient to be filtering and sorting an array every 5 seconds.

Using a collection observer your filter code will only be executed when your interface filters actually change.  *I haven't actually tested this code*

```
import { BindingEngine, Disposable, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyPage
{
    @bindable searchTerm: string;
    filteredSearchResults: any[];
    subscription: Disposable;

    constructor(private bindingEngine: BindingEngine)
    {
    }

    attached()
    {
        this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.filteredCategories).subscribe(this.filtersChanged);
    }

    detached()
    {
        this.subscription.dispose();
    }

    searchTermChanged(newValue: string, oldValue: string)
    {
        this.find();
    }

    find()
    {
         this.server.get('objects/?searchTerm=' + this.searchTerm)
                .then(groupObjects=> 
                {
                    this.searchResults = groupObjects;
                    this.update();
                });
    }

    update()
    {
        // your original filtering logic unchanged
        var filteredGroups = this.searchResults.map(res =>
        {
            let filteredGroup = new Group;
            filteredGroup = res.id,
            filteredGroup = res.name;
            filteredGroup = res.objects.filter(o => this.filteredCategories.some(fc => o.categories.some(oc => oc == fc)));
            return filteredGroup;
        });

        filteredGroups = filteredGroups.filter(fg => fg.objects.length > 0);

        // set value instead of using a computed property
        this.filteredSearchResults = filteredGroups;
    }

    filtersChanged(splices)
    {
        this.update(); // you could remove this method and bind the array observable directly to update()
    }
}
```

Comment: this is kind of like my current working implementation, but the issue here is if I then perform another search say I search "object 3", then the filtered results are not updated, because nothing is observing the searchResults property. I used the eventAggregator to publish an event called 'filterSearchResults' and have one subscription which does what you have suggested with the filtersChanged callback. I just have to publish the event everytime I want to update the results. I feel both approaches are not ideal as its not very extensible (more filters etc), thanks for your response btw!

Comment: In this case, you'd want to move your client-side filtering logic to another method, and your callback for filtersChanged, as well as the server get could execute the same function.  The event aggregator is a good solution for creating loosely coupled components, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to use it internally to a single component.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'll accept the answer even though I was hoping it would be possible somehow using the computed property. What I will do, is extend the collectionObserver to take an array of items to observe, so I only need to set it up in one place.